# how to deploy ec2 instance using ASGI django application (apache2 production)

Tags: django

please any one help to solve this issues how to deploy ec2 instance using ASGI django application (apache2 production)
.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I suggest you start by googling "deploy asgi django application to ec2" to see what is already out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Reffer these Documentation:

https://github.com/PaulleDemon/AWS-deployment/blob/master/django-channels.md